# PHP putting foreach() inside a table

Tags: php, html

First off, I'm really glad I stumbled on this website, your questions and answers helped me with my early assignments :)  Now I need help :(  What I was trying to do with my code was to create a table where it would have 3 columns "**Product**" "**Description**" "**Price**".  Under each of the following headers, I would have my arrays "`$productImage`" be under the "**Product**" column and so forth.  My problem is that I just can't seem to figure out how to make a table while using the `foreach()` function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
 <body>

<?php

   $productImage = array('http://www.rudebaguette.com/assets/PlayStation4 FeaturedImage.jpg', 'http://cdn0.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/games_consoles/Xbox%20One/Press%20shots/Xbox%20One%20family-580-90.jpg', 'http://www.blogcdn.com/de.engadget.com/media/2009/08/razer-naga-mmo-mouse-all-set-to-create-a-new-world-record11.jpg', 'http://cdn1.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/gadgets/Google%20Glass/google_glass_grey-580-90.jpg', 'http://img1.targetimg1.com/wcsstore/TargetSAS//img/p/10/02/10029875.jpg');
   $description = array('PS4 ', 'Xbox One', 'Razer Naga', 'Google Glass', 'Magic Bullet');  
   $price = array('400', '350', '70', '300', '50');
   echo '<table>';
   foreach ($productImage as $pic)
   {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>';
       echo "<img src='".$pic."' width='200' height='180'>";
       echo '</td>';
       echo '</tr>';    
   }

   foreach ($description as $des)
   {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>';
       echo $des;
       echo '</td>';
       echo '</tr>'; 
   }

   foreach ($price as $m)
   {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>';
       echo $m;
       echo '</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $productImage = array('http://www.rudebaguette.com/assets/PlayStation4 FeaturedImage.jpg', 'http://cdn0.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/games_consoles/Xbox%20One/Press%20shots/Xbox%20One%20family-580-90.jpg', 'http://www.blogcdn.com/de.engadget.com/media/2009/08/razer-naga-mmo-mouse-all-set-to-create-a-new-world-record11.jpg', 'http://cdn1.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/gadgets/Google%20Glass/google_glass_grey-580-90.jpg', 'http://img1.targetimg1.com/wcsstore/TargetSAS//img/p/10/02/10029875.jpg');
      $description = array('PS4 ', 'Xbox One', 'Razer Naga', 'Google Glass', 'Magic Bullet');  

      $price = array('400', '350', '70', '300', '50');

      echo '<table>';
    echo "<tr><td>Product</td><td>description</td><td>Price</td></tr>";
    foreach ($productImage as $key=>$pic)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>';
            echo "<img src='".$productImage[$key]."' width='200' height='180'>";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo $description[$key];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo $price[$key];
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would only need one foreach loop to do something like that, but you need to put them all in the same array:

```
<?php
// You can have an array of arrays, like such.
// This is called a multidimensional array
$array = array(
    array(
        'image' => '...',
        'desc'  => '...',
        'price' => '...'
    ),
    array(
        ...
    )
);
?>

<table>
    <?php foreach($array as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $item['image']; ?>: /></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['desc']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try it out!  Thank you soo much for the quick response :)  I'll post back with the results.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$productImage = array('http://www.rudebaguette.com/assets/PlayStation4 FeaturedImage.jpg', 'http://cdn0.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/games_consoles/Xbox%20One/Press%20shots/Xbox%20One%20family-580-90.jpg', 'http://www.blogcdn.com/de.engadget.com/media/2009/08/razer-naga-mmo-mouse-all-set-to-create-a-new-world-record11.jpg', 'http://cdn1.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/gadgets/Google%20Glass/google_glass_grey-580-90.jpg', 'http://img1.targetimg1.com/wcsstore/TargetSAS//img/p/10/02/10029875.jpg');

    $description = array('PS4 ', 'Xbox One', 'Razer Naga', 'Google Glass', 'Magic Bullet');  

   $price = array('400', '350', '70', '300', '50');

  ?>

   <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Image</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Price</th>
       </tr>
       <?php foreach ($productImage as $key => $value)
          { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><img src="<?php echo $value; ?>" /></td>
              <td><?php  echo $description[$key]; ?></td>
              <td><?php  echo $price[$key]; ?></td>
            </tr>  
          <?php }
       ?>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code this will help you.

```
echo "<table>";
for($index=0; $index<count($productImage); $index++)
{
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='{$productimage[$index]}' width='200' height='180'></td>";
    echo "<td>{$description[$index]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$price[$index]}</td>";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

but accoding to me this is not a good solution you should use array of arrays like this

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'image' => 'http://www.rudebaguette.com/assets/PlayStation4 FeaturedImage.jpg',
        'desc'  => 'PS4',
        'price' => '400'
    ),
    array(
        ...
    )
);
```

and then use this loop

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($array in $item)
{
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='{$item['image']}' width='200' height='180'></td>";
    echo "<td>{$item['desc']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$item['price']}</td>";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, I'm new to PHP and the whole coding scene.  I do remember my professor bringing up array or arrays aka he said it'll make things much more efficient.  Can't thank you guys enough!!!

Answer (score 0):

here's something that I like to use. it's a bit more generic.

```
     <?php
     $product_table = array(
         array(
             'image' => '<img src="http://www.rudebaguette.com/assets/PlayStation4 FeaturedImage.jpg" />',
             'description' => 'PS4 ',
             'price' => 400,
         ),
         array(
             'image' => '<img src="http://cdn0.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/games_consoles/Xbox%20One/Press%20shots/Xbox%20One%20family-580-90.jpg" />',
             'description' => 'Xbox One',
             'price' => 350,
         ),
         array(
             'image' => '<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/de.engadget.com/media/2009/08/razer-naga-mmo-mouse-all-set-to-create-a-new-world-record11.jpg" />',
             'description' => 'Razer Naga',
             'price' => 70,
         ),
         array(
             'image' => '<img src="http://cdn1.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/gadgets/Google%20Glass/google_glass_grey-580-90.jpg" />',
             'description' => 'Google Glass',
             'price' => 300,
         ),
         array(
             'image' => '<img src="http://img1.targetimg1.com/wcsstore/TargetSAS//img/p/10/02/10029875.jpg" />',
             'description' => 'Magic Bullet',
             'price' => 50,
         ),
     );

     $first_row = TRUE;

     echo '<table>';

     foreach ($product_table as $product_row) {
         echo "<tr>";

         foreach ($product_row as $column_name => $column_value) {
             if ($first_row) {
                 printf("<th>%s</th>", $column_name);
                 $first_row = FALSE;
             } else {
                 printf("<td>%s</td>", $column_value);
             }
         }

         echo "</tr>";
     }

     echo "</table>";
```